# How to disable/enable the row in table with the same button?

Tags: javascript, html

In my table I have one buttons . In the table I want to disable/enable the entire row with the help of the same button. the button default is enable.
I want to each row all can enable/disable when click the button of the row .
When I click on 'enable' button the entire row color will change to red and the button value change to 'disable'.
click again to the 'disable' button , thenthe entire row color recovery and the button value change to 'enable'.
How to do it . Help needed.

part of  my code :
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rZqLX/1/)

```
<table >
<tr>
    <th>Value1</td>
    <th>Value2</td>
    <th>
        <input type="button" value="enable" />
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Value3</td>
    <th>Value4</td>
    <th>
        <input type="button" value="enable" />
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the value of the button and then check if it's 'enable' or 'disable'

Here's the code:

```js
$('td input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).val((_, val) => val == "enable" ? "disable" : "enable");
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color:red;
}
table {
    padding:0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="enable" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="enable" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @kaster6398, thanks for you reply ,but it's only can click one row to disable, I cannot to disable two rows

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please, check it now.

Comment: you overcomplicate your code. You should learn to use the `toggle` function instead of using If/else and then /add/remove.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I tend to use when toggling state as per the question and using vanilla Javascript with a `delegated` event listener bound to the parent table.

```js
const cn='active';

const togglerow = (n,c) => {
  /* 
    n - the button,
    c - the class to toggle
  */
  n.dataset.tmp = n.value;
  n.value = n.dataset.alt;
  n.dataset.alt = n.dataset.tmp;
  n.removeAttribute('data-tmp');
  n.closest('tr').classList.toggle(c);
}



/*
  Bind the "click" handler to the table and inspect the `event` to
  determine the origin of the event. If the event originates on
  one of the buttons, invoke the function to toggle text/class.
*/
document.querySelector('table[data-id="todo"]').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type == 'button' ) {
    togglerow( e.target, cn )
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: monospace
}

caption {
  font-size: larger
}

table tr td {
  transition: ease-in-out background 250ms
}

th {
  background: grey;
  color: white
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.active td {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

[type='button'] {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<table data-id='todo'>
  <caption>
    A table of things that need to be done
  </caption>
  <colspan>
    <col width='40%' />
    <col width='40%' />
    <col width='20%' />
  </colspan>
  <tr>
    <th>Value 1</th>
    <th>Value 2</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="enable" data-alt='disable' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mango</td>
    <td>kiwi</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="enable" data-alt='disable' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>peach</td>
    <td>melon</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="enable" data-alt='disable' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
var all_tr = $('tr');
var all_button = $('tr input[type="button"]');
$('td input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  let newValue;
  all_tr.removeClass('selected');
  if ($(this).val() === "disable") {
    newValue = "press";
  } else {
    newValue = "disable";
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
  }
  all_button.val("press");
  $(this).val(newValue);
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color:red;
}
table {
    padding:0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value3</td>
        <td>Value4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="press" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous methods are probably better but here is another option if you use IDs for your rows or buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>JavaScript Tests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="row_1">
                <td>Value1</td>
                <td>Value2</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        id="btn_1"
                        onclick="toggle(this.id)"
                        value="enable" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row_2">
                <td>Value3</td>
                <td>Value4</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        id="btn_2"
                        onclick="toggle(this.id)"
                        value="enable" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row_3">
                <td>Value5</td>
                <td>Value6</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        id="btn_3"
                        onclick="toggle(this.id)"
                        value="enable" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row_4">
                <td>Value7</td>
                <td>Value8</td>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        id="btn_4"
                        onclick="toggle(this.id)"
                        value="enable" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        function toggle(e) {
            split_id = e.split("_");
            id = split_id[1];
            row = document.getElementById("row_" + id);
            btn = document.getElementById("btn_" + id);

            if (btn.value == "enable") {
                btn.value = "disable";
                var children = row.children;
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    var rowChild = children[i];
                    if (i <= children.length - 2) {
                        rowChild.style = "background-color: red";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                btn.value = "enable";
                var children = row.children;
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    var rowChild = children[i];
                    if (i <= children.length - 2) {
                        rowChild.style = "background-color: none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Toggle Row State</title>
    <style>
        .disabled {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Value1</th>
        <th>Value2</th>
        <th>
            <input type="button" value="enable" onclick="toggleRowState(this)" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Value3</th>
        <th>Value4</th>
        <th>
            <input type="button" value="enable" onclick="toggleRowState(this)" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function toggleRowState(button) {
        // Toggle the state based on the button's current value
        if (button.value === "enable") {
            button.value = "disable";
            // Set the row's background color to red
            button.closest("tr").classList.add("disabled");
        } else {
            button.value = "enable";
            // Remove the row's background color
            button.closest("tr").classList.remove("disabled");
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

for changing the color you have to give the class name to the particular rows and in css give the by default color let's say red color.

To achieve this functionality you can use javascript and jquery.
import the jquery in the script and write the function for toggling the button. This function that takes a button as a parameter. Inside the function, it uses jQuery to find the closest table row element to the clicked button.if the row has the class name which is given in the table then the class is removed and the button value is set to enable and vice versa.

This script will called when the button is clicked and it toggles the appearance of the row and the button text based on the current state.

Answer (score -4):

My Text is going to be Long because I am gonna explain in Detail. I solved your problem more than your Expectations. Hence, I am expecting you to Read my Text Carefully and at Slow Pace. I explained better than others, show your gratitude toward me.

***Overview of Web Page:*** Let Suppose, There is a Table in which we have 3 Column as 'Name',  'Age' and 'Gender'. Each Column have 3 Rows.

Now we created 3 Button Tag vertically
Named "Enable" below the Table. On the Left Side of each Button Tag we positioned a bold tag by Name "Change 1st, 2nd, 3rd Row Color".

Morever, We created 4 hidden Button Tag. In which 3 out of 4 have Name "Disable" at the Right Side of each non hidden Button Tag. 4th Hidden Button Tag has Name "Remove Changes" placed at the bottom of Page.

This is a Web Page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yrLK.jpg)

**HTML Code:**

```
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="15">

   <tr>

      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Gender</th>

   </tr>

   <tr>

      <td>Meow</td>
      <td>1.8</td>
      <td>Boy</td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

      <td>Dianbo</td>
      <td>0.4</td>
      <td>Boy</td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

      <td>Foster</td>
      <td>0.4</td>
      <td>Boy</td>

   </tr> 

   </table>

   <div>

     <b>Change 1st Row Color: </b>      
     <button>Enable</button> 
     <button>Disable</button>

     <b>Change 2nd Row Color: </b> 
     <button>Enable</button> 
     <button>Disable</button>

     <b>Change 3rd Row Color: </b> 
     <button>Enable</button> 
     <button>Disable</button>

   </div>

   <button style="display: none; margin-top: 04vh;">Remove Changes 
   </button>
```

**Explanation HTML Code:**

We created a Table Tag, Inside Table Tag we created 4 tr Tag. In first tr Tag we have three th tag for Column Name as mentioned in Code, In Rest 3 tr tag we have 3 td tag in each tr tag for Row's Value.

Below the Table, We have 1 Div Tag. In which Three bold Tag and six Button Tag exist. Out of 6 Button Tag, 3 Button Tag has Text "Enable" and other 3 has Text "Disable" which will be hidden later through CSS. Below the Div Tag, we created a button Tag Name "Remove Changes". It was hidden by Inline CSS as well as margin-top property was used for creating space from top.

I created bold tag so that user can clearly knows that this "Enable" Button will Change the color of specific Row into Red.

I created "Disable" Button so that user click on it for Changes Color of Rows into Blue when it First change into Red from Default (Black) Color.

I created "Remove Changes" Button so that User can restore to Default once Color of Rows changes into Red and Blue.

Web Page will Appear as After HTML:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAh4i.jpg)

**CSS Code:**

```
body{

   margin-left: 10vw;
   margin-top: 05vh;
}

table{

   border: 3px solid lightblue;
   background: lightcyan;
   table-layout: fixed;
}

tr{

   background: pink;
   text-align: center;
}

tr:first-child{
   
   background: orange;
}

div{

   white-space: pre;
   margin-top: 01vh;
}

button:nth-of-type(2n) {

   display: none;
}
```

**Explanation of CSS Code:**

I Applied Margin toward top and left in Body. It is optional, If you don't want Margin don't Use it.

I Applied border, Background and Layout Property in Table. It's better to use this property for better Look.

I applied background and text align property in tr Tag. It's Better to use for for better Look.

I changes background color of tr top tag to Orange. It is better to use because All tr tag have same color if we don't change the color.

I applied white space to avoid use br tag and Margin top to create more spaces between Table and Div Tag from Top.

I applied display property to hide the "Disable" Name button which was the even number siblings among button Tag Family.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
let btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let b = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
let tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");         


btn[0].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[0].style.display = "none";
   btn[1].style.display= "inline";

   b[0].style.color = "darkred";
   tr[1].style.background = "darkred";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});


btn[2].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[2].style.display = "none";
   btn[3].style.display = "inline";

   b[1].style.color = "darkred";
   tr[2].style.background = "darkred";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});


btn[4].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[4].style.display = "none";
   btn[5].style.display = "inline";

   b[2].style.color = "darkred";
   tr[3].style.background = "darkred";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});



btn[1].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[0].style.display = "inline";
   btn[1].style.display = "none";

   b[0].style.color = "blue";
   tr[1].style.background = "lightblue";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});


btn[3].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[2].style.display = "inline";
   btn[3].style.display = "none";

   b[1].style.color = "blue";
   tr[2].style.background = "lightblue";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});


btn[5].addEventListener("click", function() {

   btn[4].style.display = "inline";
   btn[5].style.display = "none";

   b[2].style.color = "blue";
   tr[3].style.background = "lightblue";
   btn[6].style.display = "block";

});




btn[6].addEventListener("click", function() {


   for (let i = 0; i < (btn.length - 1); i += 2) {
  
     btn[i].style.display = "inline";
     btn[i+1].style.display = "none";
   }

   for (let j = 0; j < btn.length; j++) {
  
     b[j].style.color = "black";
     tr[j+1].style.background = "pink";
     btn[6].style.display = "none";  
   }

});
```

**Explanation of JavaScript Code:**

I selected all the button Tag, tr tag and bold tag through TagName selector.

I applied same Event Listener in 1st, 3rd and 5th number Button Tag which has [0,2,4] Array position when Button Tag were selected through TagName. It's "Enable" Name Button.

I applied same Event Listener in 2nd, 4th and 6th number Button Tag which has [1,3,5] Array position when Button Tag were selected through TagName. It's "Disable" Name Button.

When User Click on 1st Button Tag Name "Enable" then it will Hide it and Visible 2nd Button Named "Disable" as well as color of 1st Row and Bold Tag Change to "Darkred", You can change into "Red". Furthermore, Last button Tag Name "Remove Changes" Also Visible.

In the Same way, When User Click on 3rd and 5th Button Tag Name "Enable" then it will Hide it and Visible 4th and 6th Button Named "Disable" as well as color of 2nd, 3rd Row and Bold Tag Change to "Darkred" according. Furthermore, Last Button "Remove Changes" Also Visible too.

When Enable Named Button Tag Hide by clicking then Disable Button Tag occupy it's position, When User Click on it then it again Hide and Enable Tag Capture their Position Again. Consequently, Color of their Respected Rows and bold Tag Changes into Blue.

At last When User Click on Remove Changes button which appeared when user click on Enable Button Tag. Consequently, It disappear again but Color of entire Rows and bold Tag again change into default which was Black in color By Default.

Comment: You clearly miss abstractions and simplicity. Your solution already scales very poorly with 5 rows. I wonder how you want to continue when facing tables with literally tens of thousands of rows.